# Enviar cada una de las string en una lista de strings a una función y luego reemplazar ese elemento de la lista con la lista que genere la función

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista, string, spacy

```py
import re, spacy

def evaluates_if_substring_is_a_verb_func(input_element):
    #----------------------------------
    #nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
    nlp = spacy.load('es_core_news_sm')

    doc = nlp(input_element)  # Your text here
    list_verbs_in_element = []
    for token in doc:
        if token.pos_ == "VERB": #Only verbs
            start = token.idx  # Start position of token
            end = token.idx + len(token)  # End position = start + len(token)
            list_verbs_in_element.append(token.text)
    #----------------------------------

    return(list_verbs_in_this_input)


#input_list:
list_verbs_in_this_input = ['correr saltar', 'llegamos', 'allí', 'hacía', 'allá', 'en', 'el', 'centro', 'habrá', '']

#llamar a la función para cada elemento de la lista por el retorno de la función

#elimine las cadenas que solo tienen espacios en blanco o están vacías

print(list_verbs_in_this_input) # --> print here to check the result
```

Necesito enviar una por una cada una de las subcadenas dentro de la lista llamada `list_verbs_in_this_input` a la función `evaluates_if_substring_is_a_verb_func()`, y reemplazar los elementos de la lista `list_verbs_in_element` que se genera en esta función por el elemento de la lista `list_verbs_in_this_input` que se envió como parámetro a esta función.

[image]

Al final y eliminando los elementos que contienen cadenas vacías o solo espacios en blanco, deberías obtener esto al imprimir la lista original:

```py
['correr', 'saltar', 'llegamos', 'habrá']
```

Comment: Creo que te convendría crear otra función que vaya recorriendo la lista vieja y vaya agregando a una lista nueva cada uno de los elementos generados por la función. El método append (agrega un item al final de la lista) y extend (que toma un iterable (como otra lista) y agrega al final todos los elementos que dicho iterable otorga). Busca "métodos de listas python" en google para más información.

Comment: Estaba intentando usar itertools porque usar append() no seria suficiente. Almenos estube intentando y no consigo estar cerca del resultado esperado

Comment: Probaste usando .extend sobre la nueva lista? Si tenes una lista que es a = ["hola", "mundo"] y otra b = ["color", "del", "mar"], a.extend(b) resultará en ["hola", "mundo", "color", "del", "mar"]

Comment: ¿Cual es la pregunta? No veo ninguna pregunta.

Comment: @CandidMoe es que no entro el "Como..." delante de la pregunta, quedaría "Como enviar cada una...". De todos modos, estaba teniendo bastantes complicaciones para hacer estas sustituciones dentro de la lista original para obtener la lista que esta en el output esperado, por eso como son sustituciones no se si serviría el método .append() sobre la lista

Comment: @DanteS. El tema de usar el .extend() es que tendrías el problema de como conectarlo con la lista del return de la función

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

Lo que puedes hacer es retornar la lista de verbos que viene de tu función e ir "sumando" las listas obtenidas de tu fución en una nueva lista que "junte" los resultados.

Ejemplo:

```
import re, spacy

def evaluates_if_substring_is_a_verb_func(input_element):
    #----------------------------------
    #nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
    nlp = spacy.load('es_core_news_sm')

    doc = nlp(input_element)  # Your text here
    list_verbs_in_element = []
    for token in doc:
        if token.pos_ == "VERB": #Only verbs
            start = token.idx  # Start position of token
            end = token.idx + len(token)  # End position = start + len(token)
            list_verbs_in_element.append(token.text)
    #----------------------------------
    
    return(list_verbs_in_element)

list_verbs_in_this_input = ['correr saltar', 'llegamos', 'allí', 'hacía', 'allá', 'en', 'el', 'centro', 'habrá', '']

result = []

for e in list_verbs_in_this_input:
    result += evaluates_if_substring_is_a_verb_func(e)

print(result)
```

Esto imprime la siguiente lista como resultado:

```
['correr', 'saltar', 'llegamos', 'hacía']
```

**Nota:** Yo creo que el modelo no está muy bien entrenado y por eso no devuelve "habrá".

Answer (score 1):

### Planteamiento

La pregunta es en realidad sobre cómo mapear una lista en otra, utilizando una función intermedia que hace la conversión. Pero el tema se complica a la hora de plantearlo o resolverlo por el hecho de que esa función intermedia es en realidad un modelo de machine learning. Esta complicación hace la pregunta un poco más confusa y sobre todo hace imposible que quien responda pueda hacer pruebas, pues carecemos del modelo entrenado.

Así que voy a reducir la pregunta a su esencia mínima, reemplazando esa función intermedia por otra "*fake*", que devuelva lo mismo que devolvería tu modelo de ML, pero sin usar modelo alguno, sino haciendo trampa. Esta sería la función:

```
def evaluates_if_substring_is_a_verb_func(input_element):
  if input_element == "correr saltar":
    return ["correr", "saltar"]
  if input_element in ["llegamos", "hacía"]:
    return [input_element]
  else:
    return []
```

Si no entendí mal la pregunta, esta función devolvería los mismos resultados que la que se muestra en el enunciado, al menos para la lista de ejemplo, pues si la palabra analizada es "correr saltar", devuelve una lista con "correr" y "saltar" por separado, si es "llegamos" o "hacía" (ambos verbos) devuelve una lista que contiene un solo elemento, con el verbo en cuestión, y si es cualquier otra palabra retorna una lista vacía por no detectar verbo (el caso en que el verbo "habrá" no es correctamente detectado como verbo no sé a qué se deberá en tu caso, pero mi función emula este caso también).

### Solución

Ahora tenemos la siguiente lista de entrada:

```
list_verbs_in_this_input = ['correr saltar', 'llegamos', 'allí', 'hacía', 'allá', 'en', 'el', 'centro', 'habrá', '']
```

y se trata de *mapear* esa lista a través de la función para generar otra. Para esta tarea Python proporciona la función `map()` que recibe como primer parámetro la función a usar y como segundo parámetro la lista a mapear, y devuelve un iterador con los resultados del mapeo. Podemos convertir ese iterador en otra lista para ver el resultado:

```
print(list(map(evaluates_if_substring_is_a_verb_func, list_verbs_in_this_input)))
```

produce:

```
[['correr', 'saltar'], ['llegamos'], [], ['hacía'], [], [], [], [], [], []]
```

Vemos que la función está devolviendo los resultados esperados, pero esta lista no es lo que queremos, ya que cada elemento de la lista es otra lista, muchas de ellas vacías. Lo que queremos es extraer los elementos de cada sublista para juntarlos todos en una única lista "plana". Para esto deberíamos iterar por cada uno de los elementos devueltos por `map()` (que es a su vez una sub-lista), e iterar por los elementos de cada sublista.

Esto puede hacerse de forma concisa con una comprensión de listas así:

```
resultado = [ elemento for sublista in map(evaluates_if_substring_is_a_verb_func, list_verbs_in_this_input)
              for elemento in sublista]
```

y `resultado` será el buscado:

```
['correr', 'saltar', 'llegamos', 'hacía']
```